# How to add mute attribute to video element within Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

With the new video autoplay policy. My video doesn't autoplay anymore. In order to fix this I need to add mute to the video but the video is added within Visual Composer and inside the video media properties there is no toggle to mute the video. How do I do this?

Comment: Which format you are using for for upload.

Comment: I am using the format mp4

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can used below plugins for muted video properties

https://wordpress.org/plugins/videojs-html5-player/

```
[videojs_video url="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/videos/myvid.mp4" muted="true"]
```

Pass your url in above shortcode for muted video.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I need the video as a background set within visual composer. So this solution doesn't work for me. I can;t add shortcodes or html are there solutions for this?